# VC 2010 Executable Not Running on Other Computers - No Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7, cocos2d-x

I'm running into a strange thing while making a game in VC++.  I'm using the Cocos2d-x platform and VC++ 2010 in Windows 7 and it works perfectly fine on my machine.  However, I have another computer that is Windows XP.  I am currently using /MT so there is no problem with the runtime library, but the program doesn't run in Windows XP and it doesn't even produce an error.  I have tried with 2010 C++ redist on the other computer, and it doesn't work with or without.  There is nothing in the console and no error log.  Nothing appears odd in DependencyWalker, only missing internet explorer frame stuff.  What can cause a program on windows XP to execute and close immediately without leaving an error?

Anyone has any ideas?  I am using the game framework's dynamic linked libraries, so could that be a problem?  Also, even though I linked statically, my executable is only about 140 KB.  Is something messing up?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:  There's also an interesting problem with CRT I ran into before.  When I ran the program with permission level "asInvoker" on windows 7, I got a "CRT Not Initialized" error.  Once I set it to "highestAllowed", it started working but I was wondering if it had anything to do with CRT?

Comment: When you say there is nothing in the console and no error log, do you mean the windows event log has no error listed or that the application didn't log anything?

Comment: The windows error log has no error listed and I don't think the application has logged anything either.  It's like the program had never run

Comment: Make sure that all linked libraries are available on the machine you wish to run it on, you may have external dependencies and when Windows cannot find them it just stops execution for no reason. You can also choose to debug the program on the target computer. 140kb sounds okay but make sure you include any .dlls you may need as well

Comment: Thanks Jesus.  All the DLLs are there, and interestingly if I remove them then the error pops up.  I will try debugging on that machine

Comment: Try installing Debugging Tools for Windows and then start the application from Windbg on that machine -- that should give you much more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found the problem.  It turns out that my other computer has an integrated Intel Graphics card that doesn't support the graphics renderer (OpenGL ES 2.0) that the framework uses.  That's why it ends up crashing without outputting any errors.

Thanks to anyone who helped.